# Trying to convert an Array to String (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

I am trying to convert an array to string using array.join() or array.toString() but it's not working as it's supposed to work. When I console.log it stays as an array.

I've the intuition that this issue comes from something related to function scopes, but I could not figure it out yet.

The project I'm trying to build is a password generator.

```js
const letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
const numbers = "0123456789";
const symbols = "!@#$%^&*_-+=";

const button = document.querySelector(".gen-pass");

button.addEventListener("click", (e) => {

  let password = [];
  
  for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    let randomLetters = letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)];
    let randomNumbers = numbers[Math.floor(Math.random() * numbers.length)];
    let randomSymbols = symbols[Math.floor(Math.random() * symbols.length)];

    password.push(randomLetters, randomNumbers, randomSymbols);
    password.join();
  }

  console.log(password);
});
```

```html
<button class="gen-pass">Generate!</button>
```

Comment: `.join()` *returns* a new string. Doesn't change the variable to be a string instead. It cannot, as that's not how JS can ever work.

Comment: You should do password.join only once after your array is complete, not inside the loop

Comment: The Array's method `join` returns a string. Try `strPassword = password.join();`. [Here is the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Array.prototype.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) returns a string. It does not change the object it is called on.

You may want to create a new variable or mutate `password` after the for loop has completed like so:

```js
const letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
const numbers = "0123456789";
const symbols = "!@#$%^&*_-+=";
let password = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    let randomLetters = letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)];
    let randomNumbers = numbers[Math.floor(Math.random() * numbers.length)];
    let randomSymbols = symbols[Math.floor(Math.random() * symbols.length)];

    password.push(randomLetters, randomNumbers, randomSymbols);
    
  }
  
  password = password.join('');

  console.log(password);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```js
const letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
const numbers = "0123456789";
const symbols = "!@#$%^&*_-+=";


const button = document.querySelector(".gen-pass");

button.addEventListener("click", (e) => {

  e.preventDefault();

  const password = Array(4).fill(0).flatMap(_ => 
    [
      letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)],
      numbers[Math.floor(Math.random() * numbers.length)],
      symbols[Math.floor(Math.random() * symbols.length)]
    ]
  ).join('');
  

  console.log(password);
});
```

```html
<button class="gen-pass">GENERATE</button>
```

basically this code generate and array of [letter, number, symbol, ...] and then it join them together

Comment: While this is a larger change to the OP's code, I like this answer best. It is the most concise. Though not as easy for beginner coders to understand.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const button = document.querySelector(".gen-pass");

button.addEventListener("click", (e) => {

  e.preventDefault();

  let password = [];
  let formattedPassword = '';

  for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    let randomLetters = letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)];
    let randomNumbers = numbers[Math.floor(Math.random() * numbers.length)];
    let randomSymbols = symbols[Math.floor(Math.random() * symbols.length)];

    password.push(randomLetters, randomNumbers, randomSymbols);

  }

  formattedPassword = password.join('');
  console.log(password, formattedPassword);
});
```

Comment: You shouldn't put the `.join` within the for loop. Also your formatting is a bit off.

Comment: thanks Jeff for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your return to the following. This moves the join to occur once at the end of password creation and removes the `,`s by telling `.join` to replace all `,`s with empty strings:

```js
const letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
const numbers = "0123456789";
const symbols = "!@#$%^&*_-+=";
const button = document.querySelector(".gen-pass");

button.addEventListener("click", (e) => {

  e.preventDefault();

  let password = [];
  
  for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    let randomLetters = letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)];
    let randomNumbers = numbers[Math.floor(Math.random() * numbers.length)];
    let randomSymbols = symbols[Math.floor(Math.random() * symbols.length)];

    password.push(randomLetters, randomNumbers, randomSymbols);
  }

  console.log(password.join(""));
});
```

```html
<button type="button" class="gen-pass">Generate Password</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of is by using JSON which is known for converting data to strings. Check this stringify function out here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp?msclkid=e8639fd0cfa411eca470fe06b0ce6da7

Comment: You are new to SO, so I wanted to give you a bit of advice. When answering questions it is best to put examples or explanation as to the solution rather than an external link. Among many reasons, a major one is that we can not guarantee that link will be good a year from now. It is fine to link to something external WITH an answer so a user may look for further reading.